# MySQL Operand should contain 2 column(s) error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting an error with the following SQL query. I'm almost positive it's the last line, but I can't figure out how to structure it correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM listfinal
    WHERE  (CourseID IN (SELECT CourseID FROM listfinal WHERE CourseID ='A E200'))
    AND (SELECT `Start Time`,`End Time` FROM listfinal WHERE `Days` LIKE ('%M%')) IN ((`Start Time` < 800 OR `Start Time` >= 1500) AND (`End Time` < 800 OR `End Time` >= 1500))
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 2 column(s)

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 2 column(s)

Comment: edit the question and add it to the question

Comment: Just did - it's also in the title.

Comment: You should probably try using `JOIN`s here instead of all these subqueries.

Comment: What *exactly* are you looking for in your `listfinal` table?  What data does `listfinal` contain?

Comment: `listfinal` is my school's class registration database (CourseID, Start Time, End Time, Days, etc.). I'm trying to filter out classes where `Days` (i.e "MWF") includes the letter "M" for monday, "T" for tuesday, etc. AND their times conflict with a user input (ex. busy from 900 until 1200)

Answer (score 1):

So, you have this:

```
SELECT * FROM listfinal
    WHERE (CourseID IN (SELECT CourseID 
                          FROM listfinal 
                         WHERE CourseID ='A E200'))
```

so far, so good.  But then this does not make sense:

```
      AND (SELECT `Start Time`,`End Time` 
             FROM listfinal 
            WHERE `Days` LIKE '%M%')
```

because you cannot `AND` a subquery, and this does not make sense, either:

```
IN ( (`Start Time` < 800 OR `Start Time` >= 1500) 
   AND (`End Time` < 800 OR `End Time` >= 1500) )
```

The `IN` operator accepts a list of values as parameters.  You have not given it a list of values, you have given it a boolean expression.  You need to rethink this.  I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, so I can't tell for sure what you want to do, but you are probably looking for something like this:

```
AND (`Start Time` < 800 OR `Start Time` >= 1500) 
AND (`End Time` < 800 OR `End Time` >= 1500)
```

Comment: I am trying to phrase the query that basically says, "Select all the classes that have this CourseID. Then, if any of these classes correspond to a value of '%M%' in its respective column `Days`, don't display the ones where `Start Time` or `End Time` are between 800 and 1500. Show all other results."

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the correct phraseology.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  How about phrasing it like this: "Select all the classes that have this CourseID, and their 'Days' correspond to a value of '%M%', and their End-Time is before 800 or their Start-Time is after 1500".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a similar query:

```
SELECT * FROM listfinal T1
    WHERE  (T1.CourseID IN (SELECT T3.CourseID FROM listfinal T3 WHERE T3.CourseID ='A E200'))
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM listfinal  T2 WHERE T2.`Days` LIKE ('%M%') AND
                (T2.`Start Time` < 800 OR T2.`Start Time` >= 1500) AND 
                (T2.`End Time` < 800 OR T2.`End Time` >= 1500) AND
                   T1.`Start Time` = T2.`Start Time` AND 
                   T1.`End Time` = T2.`End Time`)
```

**References**

- https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php
- https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/exists.php